# moving funds from contract that owns all total supply

Tags: solidity, erc-20

[image]

So I've given the total supply to this contract via making an address state variable `address creditsContract = address(this)`, and was wondering if I could call the transfer function from another contract, with `credits.approve(msg.sender, _amount)` and `credits.transferFrom(creditsContract, _to, _amount)` .

Would ^ work or would I need to do something else to make this work?

I just don't want to make the total supply go to a wallet, to increase security that the owner wont just run away with the funds, like SushiSwap (I know he put them back, luckily for SushiSwap).

Another thing with the above sequence is that if my contract is able to do this, wouldn't another smart contract dev be able to do this as well and then be able to drain the contract of the funds?

Thank you!

Comment: "`if my contract is able to do this, wouldn't another smart contract dev be able to do this as well and then be able to drain the contract of the funds?`" - a good point, which essentially answers your question: no, your contract is not able to do this, and you wouldn't want it to be able to do this, for the exact reason that you've mentioned - if your contract was able to do that, then another contract would also be able to do that.

Comment: maybe there is a way of getting around this?